# prevent XSS attacks In JSPs

Tags: jsp, security, xss, owasp, esapi

I want to prevent XSS attacks in my web app, so I want to escape the data entered by the user in a form before save it on the DB to show it in another JSP page, and I am hesitating between 2 approaches:

`StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()` , that for the input **REGGAETON / SALSA** give me the same result, 
but for `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML()` that for the same input the output will be **REGGAETON & #x2f; SALSA**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do not save escaped data, escape it when you need to display it**:

**The way to escape it depends of the context you wants to display it**, so if you save it escaped, it will be only usable in that context, and most of the time, escaping functions are not bijectives, so **you will loose information**.

For the way to encode it to display it **in an html context**, both ways seams correct.

Additionally, to improve the protection against XSS, **you should look into CSP** (content security policy), it helps a lot, especially for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use PreparedStatement to enter data into your database. Don't escape them as this may lead to losing the original data.

In the jsp file, whenever you want to dispaly a value that has been entered by user then you can go for this:

```
<c:out value="${variable}" escapeXml="true"/>
```